# Kubernetes cert-manager with letsencrypt, challenge pending?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

This is the status of my certificate:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2021-04-07T21:43:09Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
    Last Transition Time:        2021-04-07T21:43:10Z
    Message:                     Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                      Ready
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Ready
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  homeautomation-tls-secret-rcq5l
  Not After:                     2021-07-06T21:43:10Z
  Not Before:                    2021-04-07T21:43:10Z
  Renewal Time:                  2021-06-06T21:43:10Z
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                From          Message
  ----    ------     ----               ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    13m                cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  13m                cert-manager  Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "homeautomation-tls-secret-rcq5l"
  Normal  Requested  13m                cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "homeautomation-tls-secret-wzvm8"
  Normal  Issuing    13m (x2 over 13m)  cert-manager  Issued temporary certificate
```

When checking the Challenge, I get this:

```
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: did not get expected response when querying endpoint, expected "dD7r5-43sZ_9SXZWHsK6I3WRO1mP4EMeJx3zwcvNsfo.QCUeQgKws4fAcr_fkpJwEpGdXCzbNMUU-CH3SUIrGK0" but got:
  State:       pending
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----          -------
  Normal  Started    6m30s  cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented  6m30s  cert-manager  Presented challenge using HTTP-01 challenge mechanism
```

When I try to browse the site from Firefox, I get:

Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

It's look like I got a temporary self-signed certificate issued, but not the real letsencrypt certificate.

I have these annotations on my Ingress:

```
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    cert-manager.io/issue-temporary-certificate: "true"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232839/404-challenge-response-with-cert-manager-and-nginx-ingress  https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3442 ?

Comment: @Malgorzata I took a look, but it doesn't look like it's a similar issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment (cloud provider, version of kubernetes, whole yaml files and steps you have followed so far, tutorials if you used ones) ?

Comment: @OlavT did you manage to solve it in the meantime? Looks just like the issue I'm facing right now